# Freemarker Scripting with NetSuite Advanced PDF and Saved Searches

Tags: pdf, freemarker, netsuite

New to Freemarker. I am trying to create an Advanced PDF off a Saved Search. One column in the Saved Search is using the following calculation:

> ROUND((SUM((case when {today}-{transaction.trandate} BETWEEN 1 AND 85
>   and {transaction.type} IN ('Item Fulfillment') then
>   {transaction.quantity}else 0 end) / 6) 
>   -Max({custitem_dp_prepackqtyonhand})), -1)

How can I recreate this calculation in my Advanced PDF template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to recreate the formula in Advanced PDF template. You can give a name to the custom formula field you created by using 'custom label' and this field will be available in the Advanced PDF template.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I've been trying, but it's strange. The formula I want to bring in is not available in the Advanced PDF/HTML. All other formulas from the Saved Search are available except for one. There is nothing different about its settings. I also get the following error from the Saved Search: We cannot return search columns for summary saved search {1}.

Comment: I'm sure you have another Formula with the same return type. Even though  you gave them different custom labels, Netsuite treats them all with the same id. All Formula(Numeric) will be referenced as Formulanumeric. If you have another fomula(numeric) , remove it and this one will appear in the Advanced PDF.

Comment: Another option could be to create a custom field based on your formula for the specific record type that you want and it will be available everywhere.

Comment: Actually, the first Formula(Numeric) field is referenced by 'formulanumeric' in Advanced PDF templates. The second Formula(Numeric) field is referenced by 'formulanumeric_1', the third by 'formulanumeric_2' and so on... Another thing is, that searches with summary fields cannot be used in the templates. You should create a script, adding custom data source to the renderer.